# Is it correct to call store.load() in the view init?

Tags: extjs, model-view-controller

I'm new to extJS. I have an app with a main controller that properly fires a new view creation. The view is presenting data coming from a store connected to it. I invoke the load command from inside the view init function:

```
var store = this.getStore();
   ....
    this.getStore().load();
```

this should not be correct in my opinion, even if I found some examples like the code above. Is there a better event to intercept from the controller to load the data and properly render the view?

Comment: It depends. If the load is asynchronous then by the time it loads everything will already be rendered.

Comment: It is asynchronous actually. And at present I have a proper "laoding" progress display on the view

Comment: In that case I'd just load it in the controller in the same place I'm creating the view. Or set `autoLoad` on the store if you're creating an instance when you create the view.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli it works :) Add hte reply and I will accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

Well you could do something like this in your controller, to make sure the view doesn't show before the store is actually loaded.

```
var store = Ext.getStore('store');
store.on('load', function(store) {

// if the store is correctly loaded show the view

});
```

And set your view to config parameter 'store' to your store. You can get your data in a tpl using {store_value}.